# "Eu prefiro ir ao cinema do que ficar aqui parado" é uma construção gramatical aceitável?

Tags: gramática, preposições

No Brasil pouco se ouve "prefiro isto a aquilo" no Português falado. Muitos falam "eu prefiro isso do que aquilo". A forma correta, no entanto, seria "eu prefiro ir ao cinema a ficar aqui parado". Minha pergunta é: "do que" é uma forma aceitável? Em Portugal também usam "do que"?

Comment: "Eu prefiro ir ao cinema em vez de ficar aqui parado." ou "Eu prefiro ir ao cinema do que ver o filme na televisão." acho que é como se usa em Portugal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se considerarmos a [gramática normativa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%C3%A1tica_normativa), **não**:

> Chama-se gramática normativa a gramática que busca ditar ou prescrever as regras gramaticais de uma língua, posicionando as suas prescrições como a única forma correta de realização da língua e categorizando as outras formas possíveis como erradas.

Entretanto:

> Enquanto a gramática normativa considera como erro o uso de formas diferentes da norma culta da língua (tornada oficial), na perspectiva da gramática descritiva, o erro gramatical **não existe** [...]

Fonte: [Gramática descritiva](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%C3%A1tica_descritiva)

Em outras palavras, a dita "norma culta da língua" pode ditar quantas regras ela quiser, mas **"prefiro isto do que aquilo" é perfeitamente gramatical**.

Answer (score 7):

A priori, não. [Não é a regência culta do verbo "preferir"](http://educacao.uol.com.br/dicas-portugues/regencia-do-verbo-preferir-ainda-causa-duvida.jhtm).

A confusão começa porque "preferir" é usado com a mesma regência do verbo "gostar", cuja transitividade é diferente. [Este link explica isso bem](http://www.jurisway.org.br/v2/pergunta.asp?idmodelo=6796).